# Flash: How do I make a POST request from within flash to my processing php page?

Tags: flash, http, forms, http-post

I basically have a form inside of Flash that I need to submit to a server-side processing page, which will then return either json or xml telling if it succeeded or not ( json, xml I suppose ). My version of Flash is CS4 and I'm wondering if there are any libraries or frameworks I can use to accomplish this.

Comment: AS3 - looks like the first answer is what I need, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figuring out how a framework works or a complete library shouldn't be less work than uses the provided flash classes.

Everything you might need is build into flash, except a JSON library which can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/).

Take a look at the URLRequest and the URLLoader class in the [actionscript 3 reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use URLRequest, and set its method to URLRequestMethod.POST. For setting request parameters use URLvariables.